# jQuery Regular expressions to extract string?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following string with line breaks \r\n:

```
var myString = "DTSTART:20161009T160000Z
                DTEND:20161009T170000Z
                RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20161015T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
                EXDATE:20161009T160000Z"
```

I want to extract the rrule as follows:

```
FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20161015T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
```

Currently I can achieve this by doing the following

```
var subStr = myString.match("RRULE:(.*)\r\n");
alert(subStr[1]);
```

Sometimes the EXDATE line doesn't exist in which case there is no \r\n after the RRULE line. Anyone know of a cleaner way to do it without having to output using an array index?

Comment: Just `/RRULE:(.*)/` should be enough, or this looks more precise - `/^\s*RRULE:(.*)/m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `\r\n` at all since `.` matches any symbol but a linebreak symbol (neither `\r`, nor `\n`). A mere `/RRULE:(.*)/` can work for you. For better precision, you may specify you want a `RRULE`  that is at the start of a line with

```
/^\s*RRULE:(.*)/m
```

See the demo:

```js
const myString = `DTSTART:20161009T160000Z
                DTEND:20161009T170000Z
                RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20161015T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA`;
let m;
m = myString.match(/^\s*RRULE:(.*)/m);
if (m) {
 console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: what does the `m` do at the end of expression?

Comment: It is a multiline modifier making `^` match the start of a line instead of a start of a string.